# VueJS: Use v-model and :value in the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I'am searching a way to use `v-model` and `:value` in same time on the same object.

I got this error:

> `:value="user.firstName"` conflicts with `v-model` on the same element
>   because the latter already expands to a value binding internally.

The purpose is to set as default value the value get from the `mapGetters` (coming from one store) and to set the right value when the user will submit the modification. (in `onSubmit`)

```vue
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">
        {{ $t("firstname") }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-7">
        <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" v-model="firstname" :value="user.firstName">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            lang: "",
            firstname: ""
        }
    },
    computed: mapGetters([
        'user'
    ]),
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'updateUserProfile'
        ]),
        onChangeLanguage () {
            this.$i18n.locale = lang;
        },
        // Function called when user click on the "Save changes" btn
        onSubmit () {
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onSaveChanges() - called');
            const userData = {
                firstName: this.firstname
            }
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onSaveChanges() - called', userData);
            //this.updateUserProfile(userData);
        },
        // Function called when user click on the "Cancel" btn
        onCancel () {
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onCancel() - called');
            this.$router.go(-1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you want to set the "initial" value of the `v-model` on the object itself, like:

```js
data() {
  return {
    firstname: 'someName'
  }
}
```

But since you're getting it from the store, you could access the specific getter object with `this.$store.getters[your_object]`, so I would remove the `:value` binding and use `v-model` alone for this:

```vue
<div class="col-7">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" v-model="firstname">
</div>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lang: "",

      firstname: this.$store.getters.user.firstName
    }
  },

  // ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I will keep in mind that the best choice is to declare variable in data object whatever the initial value comes from

Comment: @wawanopoulos No problem. Even though we could reach out for objects from the store directly, we might really want to limit the "scope" to the current component only, since we're using them as a `v-model` which means they are prone to changes; and with Vuex, we probably can't mutate states without using [`store.commit()`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit).

Answer (score 3):

The Vue `v-model` directive is syntactic sugar over `v-bind:value` and `v-on:input`. [This alligator.io article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/) helped me a lot to understand how it works.

So basically your problem is that the `v-model` directive sets `value` to `firstname`, while you're also explicitly setting `value` to `user.firstName`.

There are a lot of ways to handle this issue. I think a fast and straightforward solution is to store the `firstname` as a data variable (as you're already doing), and then use only `v-model` with it, disregarding `v-bind:value`.

Then, to set the user from the store for the default username, you could set `fristname` as the store user's username in the `created` hook:

#### script:

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    created() {
      this.firstname = this.user.username; // is this right? no used to the map getters syntax, but this is the idea
    },
    data () {
        return {
            lang: "",
            firstname: ""
        }
    },
    computed: mapGetters([
        'user'
    ]),
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'updateUserProfile'
        ]),
        onChangeLanguage () {
            this.$i18n.locale = lang;
        },
        // Function called when user click on the "Save changes" btn
        onSubmit () {
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onSaveChanges() - called');
            const userData = {
                firstName: this.firstname
            }
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onSaveChanges() - called', userData);
            //this.updateUserProfile(userData);
        },
        // Function called when user click on the "Cancel" btn
        onCancel () {
            console.log('Component(Profile)::onCancel() - called');
            this.$router.go(-1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only use v-model, it will create a 2-way binding with the value in your script: changing the variable in js will update the input element, interacting with the input element will update the variable.

If you want to use a default value, just set the variable to that value (wherever it may come from).